# best result for salt and pepper

Tags: matlab, image-processing

i have a picture with salt and pepper noise added to it. my task is to remove it using these functions :

You may use matlab functions ginput, to find specific points in the image (of course in the script you should hard code the coordinates you need).

You may use conv2, fft2, ifft2, fftshift etc.

You may also use median, mean, max, min, sort, etc.

As far as i can tell. i can use MinMax filter or Median Filter.

my task is to get the best results! so far i think Median filter will get me that.

is median filter really better than doing MinMaxMinMax.... ? is there a better way to get better results?

Comment: "I know it's a DSP question but no one ever uses [dsp.stackexchange.com](http://dsp.stackexchange.com)" -- this is simply not true - traffic is low there but the signal-to-noise ratio is very high, and qood questions typically get good answers very quickly (same day usually).

Comment: @PaulR ok i removed my comment....

Comment: You should probably flag your question too and ask a mod to migrate it to dsp.se where it belongs.

Comment: It would be also great if you could define what "the best results" are in order to get better answer to your question.

Comment: @Tom right thanks. well i have to decide what is considered to be best. i guess that if you take one specific picture. best is the result closest to the origin...

Comment: The methods you mention are very simplistic in relation to what can be done. For instance, check the paper "Salt-and-Pepper Noise Removal by Median-type Noise Detectors and Detail-preserving Regularization" by Chan, Ho, Nikolova. Looking at other questions I've approached and were closed because were considering "offtopic for SO" (or something equivalent), I will wait some time before putting any time into including an answer here.

Comment: "The best results" most likely refers to higher PSNR, that is a very common measure for any method that is dealing with noise extraction. I don't really think giving this definition improves the chances of getting better answers.

Comment: What can improve the received answers is removing the restriction of matlab (indicated by its tag), which is pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A median filter is a great way and text book approach to address salt an pepper noise. Matlab offers a function `medfilt2` for this purpose, but of course you can also code your own by calculating the center intensity of a 3x3 window `w` using `median(w(:))`.

Comment: i have implemented median filter and i want to use it. but is it better than minmanminman filter?

Comment: Median filter is only "a great way" to remove salt & pepper when the noise level is low. At not-so-low noise level, median filter causes serious distortion effects and might not remove the noise too.